# How to parallel insert into Hive using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I have a job which is splitted among workers, each worker outputs a dataframe which needs to be written into hive, I couldn't figure out how to access hive from workers without initializing another sparkcontext so I tried collecting their output and inserting it in one time like below

```
result = df.rdd.map(lambda rdd: predict_item_by_model(rdd, columns)).collect()
df_list = sc.parallelize(result).map(lambda df: hiveContext.createDataFrame(df)).collect() #throws error
mergedDF = reduce(DataFrame.union, df_list) 
mergedDF.write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy("item_id").saveAsTable("items")
```

but now it throws this error

`_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.`

is there away to access hive from workers directly ? if not, how can I collect the data and insert them once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.map(lambda df: hiveContext.createDataFrame(df))
```

Simply not possible in Spark this approach. Not how it works at all.

The first step of any Spark driver application is to create a SparkContext including Hive context, if required. Driver aspect only. As the message states.

Have a look here https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark/serialization-issues-part-1/read to get yourself going on this serialization issue.